# Selectig entries in a pandas data frame with an array

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame built on an object with multiple attributes. Lets call this data1. data1 has an array x which associates every entry in the data frame with a set of values and arrays y and z which do the same. My code looks as follows.

```
x = (3, 5, 2, 8, 9)
y = (4, 9, 0, 2, 1)
z = (0, 3, 6, 0, 2)

cols = ['x', 'y', 'z']
data1.loc[:5, cols]
```

this returns a table with columns x, y, and z. The entries in the table correspond to the arrays above. What I need to do is use another array to select the corresponding entries in the table. For example, lets say the array is

```
idx = [1, 4, 5]
```

I need to return a table exactly like the one given above but only containing the entries in the idx array. I have tried:

```
cols = ['x', 'y', 'z']
data1.loc[idx, cols]
```

This returns a table that is identical to the previous table but now all the entries are scattered. If the code should return only the entries corresponding to (1,4,5) it returns (1,4,5,2,3).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (remember index start at 0):

```
import pandas as pd
x = (3, 5, 2, 8, 9)
y = (4, 9, 0, 2, 1)
z = (0, 3, 6, 0, 2)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = x
df['y'] = y
df['z'] = z
print(df);print()

idx = [1, 4, 2] 
cols = ['x', 'y', 'z']
print(df.loc[idx, cols])

   x  y  z
1  5  9  3
4  9  1  2
2  2  0  6
```